# Looking for music streaming software that allows any user to queue up songs

Tags: streaming, playlists, music-management

I work in an office and we have a server with a lot of music on it. I am looking for software that would allow anyone in the office to queue up songs to a playlist, sort of like an office radio station where people choose the songs. Are there any programs like this already written? I am considering writing software like this but I'm not sure if it already exists.

Comment: You can try Winamp

Comment: Should we assume a Windows network with Windows clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ampache](http://ampache.org/) is a web-based A/V streaming application.  It can be configured to play via embedded flash or stream to a local media player on a per-user basis, or it can be configured for democratic playlists to allow many users to vote on what they want to hear.

It's done in PHP with a basic LAMP stack and isn't too difficult to modify.

Answer (score 1):

It's old, but it still works. [Tunez](http://tunez.sourceforge.net/) is an open source web jukebox. Runs under linux, and uses mpg123 to stream to icecast. It has voting capabilities among other things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at work, and it's blocked, but [Orb](http://mycast.orb.com) gives you a web based interface.

Also check out this [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/256052/how-to-stream-your-music-to-any-pc) article.

Answer (score 0):

Would each person connect separately, or is there one player connected to speakers?

My personal favourite is Squeezecenter. If you are all using PCs you can use the Jive UI to connect to it.

An alternative some people use in our office is Spotify. You can have a group playlist that people add music to and take away.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify allows for shared playlists.